# Load tab one by one in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, performance, tabs, load

I'm french so excuse-me for my english.

I'm using AngularJS for my tabs. It works good, but it's a big page and it takes too time to load. So I'd like to ask to Angular to load only the active tab and to don't touch to the others.

Do you know if it's easily possible?

Thank's a lot

Comment: How did you create yours tabs? Are they all in the same component / template ?

Comment: I use some <uib-tab> inside of an <uib-tabset>
Is it what you wanted to know?

Comment: yes. So what take time is not the rendering but the first loading of files used by your application, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. The first loading, and then a few details on some angular grids

Comment: This is the goal of a Single Page Application provided by Angular to load every thing at the beginning. 
To reduce this loading time you can think to minify yours files and avoid loading big size ressources.